# Z-transform: Convolution <=> Multiplication giving strange results

Tags: signal-processing, z-transform

I try two slightly different routes to an answer, and get two different answers. (This is from a past exam paper.)

Find h[n] if $ H(z) = \frac{1}{(1-az^{-1})^2} $

**First try**:

$ H(z) = H_1(z)\cdot H_2(z) $,

$ H_1(z) = a^{-1}z $, $ \qquad H_2(z) = \frac{az^{-1}}{(1-az^{-1})^2}$

According to Wikipedia,

$ \mathcal{Z^{-1}}(a^{-1}z) = a^{-1} \delta[n+1]$

$ \mathcal{Z^{-1}}(\frac{az^{-1}}{(1-az^{-1})^2}) = na^n $, $ \qquad n > 0$

Therefore, since multiplication in the Z domain is convolution in the time domain,

$ h[n] = a^{-1} \delta[n+1] \ast na^n = a^{-1}(n+1)a^{n+1} = (n+1)a^n $.

$ (n+1)a^n $ is the answer given in the solution. However...

**Second try:**

$ H(z) = H_3(z)^2, \qquad H_3(z) = \frac{1}{(1-az^{-1})} $

$ \therefore h[n] = h_3[n] \ast h_3[n] = a^n \ast a^n = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} a^k \cdot a^{n-k} $

**But:**

$ \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} a^k \cdot a^{n-k} \neq (n+1)a^n $

Comment: Your extraordinarily bad choice of notation (probably something inherited from a bad textbook) is part of the reason what you are having difficulties. Be that as it may, keep in mind that $$h_3[n] = \begin{cases}0,&n < 0,\\a^n,&n \geq 0,\end{cases}$$ and so your sum simplifies to a sum not from $k=-\infty$ to $k=\infty$ but only for $0 \leq k \leq n$ (i.e. only $(n+1)$ terms) and the difficulty disappears.

Comment: lol! What aspect of my notation is extraordinarily bad? I'd honestly like to know. And thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Not specifying ROC / ranges for which the function is as written?

Comment: `What aspect of my notation is extraordinarily bad?` There is a general convention followed by mathematicians (but apparently not by signal processors) that a symbol should mean the same thing no matter where it occurs in a formula. When you write $$h[n] = h_3[n] \ast h_3[n] = a^n \ast a^n = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} a^k \cdot a^{n-k}$$ those $n$'s do not all have the same meaning.  When you replace $h_3[n]$ by $a^n$, you are asserting that _for every integer_ $n$, $h_3[n]$ equals $a^n$ which is false, and it misleads you into writing the sum on the right, where $n$ means something else.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing fine. You only have a problem with the convolution. We define the convolution [(Cauchy product)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) of two sequences as

> $$ a_n*b_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_i b_{n-i}. $$

So, in your case, we have

> $$ a^n*a^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} a^i a^{n-i}=a^n\sum_{i=0}^{n}1 = (n+1) a^n.$$